# Read AirPlay Audio Device Type (HomePod, Apple TV, etc)

Tags: swift, avfoundation, media-player, airplay

I am trying to get info about a connected AirPlay device using

```
    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    
    guard let output = currentRoute.outputs.first else {
        return
    }
```

When connected to HomePod or Apple TV, I can get the `output.portType` which is `.airplay` and the `output.portName` which is just `"AirPlay"`. I would love to get the type of device my app is connected to.

I've tried using the `output.uid` but HomePods don't seem to follow any discernable pattern as compared to other AirPlay devices.

It seems very strange that I would not be able to see the type of device connected, or at least the name. I'm starting to suspect that this isn't possible, but I just wanted to make sure there are no other frameworks or ideas anyone else has.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of information that Apple would explicitly prevent you from obtaining on privacy grounds.